# Subsequence in compact metrical space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces, compactness

> Let $X$ be a compact metrical space and $(x_n)\subset X$ a sequence. Show that $x_n\to x$ iff for every convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}\to x$.

"$\Leftarrow$" is true since $(x_n)\subset (x_n)$ is a subsequence.

"$\Rightarrow$" Let $(x_{n_k})$ be a convergent subsequence of $(x_n)$ with limit $y$. Now I probably need to use the compactness of $X$ to show that $x=y$. However, after looking up the definition of compactness I am slightly confused by how many different definitions there are. Which definition do I use here and how can I obtain $x=y$ with it?

Comment: The "$\Leftarrow$" is not as easy as it seems: by [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), you know that every sequence has a converging subsequence, but you don't know *a proiri* that $x_n$ is convergent (there could be several accumulation points).

Comment: Can't I just take the exact same sequence? If $x_{n_k}\to x$ for every subsequence then surely for $x_n$ itself, right?

Comment: For every **convergent** subsequence. And you don't know yet that $x_n$ is convergent.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, by looking at José's prove below I assume this also works by contradiction? Suppose there is a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $x_{n_k}\to y\neq x$, then we can't have $x_n\to x$.

Comment: José's proof below applies to the "$\Leftarrow$" case (by [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive)). The $\Rightarrow$" case follows from the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit.

Comment: Okay. So let's saay $x_n\to x$ and let's take a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$. If $x_{n_k}\to y\neq x$, then $y$ is an accumulation point of $x_n$. Can I now conclude that $y=x$ because $X$ is compact? I only know that compact spaces have an accumulation point but I'm not sure if it is unique in some conditions.

Comment: In the "$\Rightarrow$" case, you can use the fact that $x_n$ is convergent. If $x_{n_k}\to y\ne x$, then $x_n$ is *not* convergent, because $\exists \,\varepsilon>0, \forall\,N, \exists\,n, n>N \wedge |x_n-x|>\varepsilon$ Take $\varepsilon = |x-y|/2$ for instance. The $n$ in this statement can be taken from $n_k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$. Then there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for every $p\in\mathbb N$, there is a natural $n\geqslant p$ such that $d(x_n,x)\geqslant\varepsilon$. So, you can defined a sequence $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ as follows:

- $n_1$ is such that $d(x_{n_1},x)\geqslant\varepsilon$;
- $n_{k+1}>n_k$ and $d(x_{k+1},x)\geqslant\varepsilon$.

Then the sequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ has a convergente subsequence (since the space is compact), whse limit cannot be $x$. This subsequence is a subsequence of the original sequence, but its limit is not $x$.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!

Comment: @Buh If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Of course, I was just finishing the other direction above as there were severe understanding problems.